# java os x enumerate windows/window locations

Tags: java, macos, screen, snapshot

I'm familiar with using ffi+jruby to enumerate windows/window locations in java+windows by calling into the windows api's...anybody know how to do such a thing in OS X (enumerate windows, their locations, titles et al)?

Thanks!

-roger-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://programming-gone-awry.blogspot.com/2011/08/mac-os-x-enumerate-windows-like-windows.html seems to show the available options.

http://forum.soft32.com/mac/Enumerating-windows-ftopict46287.html

[How can I programatically move one Terminal.app window to another space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308820/how-can-i-programatically-move-one-terminal-app-window-to-another-space)

[How do I get a list of the window titles on the Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606321/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-window-titles-on-the-mac-osx)

Do you have to use some accessibility API or something...